# How can i pass activationdata in child routing in durandal js?

Tags: durandal

I want to pass some data with navigation parameter through router.navigate method in duarndal js.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a route like:

```
{
    route    : 'foo/:id/:bar',
    title    : 'Foo',
    moduleId : 'viewmodels/foo',
    nav      : true
}
```

In which case your `navigate` would be:

```
router.navigate('foo/123/abc');
```

And in your `viewmodel` you can collect the variables and use them:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'knockout'], function(router, app, ko) {
    var paramId;
    var paramBar;

    return {
        activate: function(id, bar) {
            paramId  = id;
            paramBar = bar; 
        }
    };
});
```